# Explode string on commas and trim potential spaces from each value

Tags: php, trim, explode, higher-order-functions, preg-split

For example, I would like to create an array from the elements in this string:

```
$str = 'red,     green,     blue ,orange';
```

I know you can explode and loop through them and trim:

```
$arr = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $new_arr[] = trim($value);
}
```

But I feel like there's a one line approach that can handle this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 585, accepted):

You can do the following using [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$new_arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', $str));
```

Comment: This is also looping (internally) by PHP

Comment: @JasonOOO I think in most people's opinion, a couple milliseconds (if even that) is a fair tradeoff for having a line of code that is short, simple and easily readable.

Comment: Simple and easy to understand. However, if dealing with large data sets, the more performant answer provided by @amr-eladwy is the better solution.

Answer (score 75):

An improved answer

```
preg_split ('/(\s*,*\s*)*,+(\s*,*\s*)*/', 'red,     green thing ,,
              ,,   blue ,orange');
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green thing
    [2] => blue
    [3] => orange
)
```

This:

- Splits on commas only
- Trims white spaces from each item.
- Ignores empty items
- Does not split an item with internal spaces like "green thing"

Comment: Can anyone explain me why this answer does not have 100 upvotes?  Regexp is hard to understand, but it parsed my 100Mb file faster than other solutions

Comment: Sorry but this regex is wrong - try replacing `red` with `*red*`. A better one might be /(\s*,\s*)+/

Comment: @AmrElAdawy FYI this no longer works after the 8/28 update. With the regex in the answer as-is, white space is not trimmed from some of the elements. Ex: `     green thing`.

Comment: Hi @Samsquanch , can you help me more about that update? Do you have fiddler I can play around with?

Comment: @AmrElAdawy here you go: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rrI#tab-preg-split

Comment: @Samsquanch  updated. Please let me know if you see any issue.

Comment: Why your regexp not trim spaces around string? Example:
'  red,     green thing ,,  ,,   blue ,orange  '

Answer (score 27):

The following also takes care of white-spaces at start/end of the input string:

```
$new_arr = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', trim($str));
```

and this is a minimal test with white-spaces in every sensible position:

```
$str = ' first , second , third , fourth, fifth ';
$new_arr = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', trim($str));
var_export($str);
```

Comment: Since `array_map` and regexp solutions produce identical results, could anyone compare their performance?

Comment: @Dan For cases like this, it will not be any difference.

Answer (score 10):

this how you replace and explode in a single line of code

```
$str = 'red,     green,     blue ,orange';

$new_string = explode(',',preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str));
```

will output the results as

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
    [3] => orange
)
```

Comment: this removes space within string. eg., 'navy blue' becomes 'naviblue'

Answer (score 6):

By combining some of the principals in the existing answers I came up with

```
preg_split ('/\s*,+\s*/', 'red,     green thing ,,  ,,   blue ,orange', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The reasoning behind it is that I found a bug in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38300330/3179038), where if there is a comma at the end of the string it'll return a blank element in the array. i.e.

```
preg_split ('/(\s*,*\s*)*,+(\s*,*\s*)*/', 'red,     green thing ,,  ,,   blue ,orange,');
```

Results in

```
Array
(
  [0] => red
  [1] => green thing
  [2] => blue
  [3] => orange
  [4] => ''
)
```

You can fix this by using **PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY** as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24510025/3179038) to remove it, but once you are doing that there is technically no need to remove consecutive commas via the regex, thus the shortened expression

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with a one line regex

```
preg_split('@(?:\s*,\s*|^\s*|\s*$)@', $str, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: it creates multiple matches for spaces before and after in a string, for example " one, two, three  " generates: Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    [3] => three
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", 'red,     green,     blue ,orange');
```

Comment: The OP wants an array.  `preg_replace()` doesn't generate an array from a string.  This is the right answer to the wrong question.   Downvoted.

Comment: `$list = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", 'red,     green,     blue ,orange');` minor modification rehabilitates the answer

Answer (score 1):

**SPECIFICALLY** for the OP's sample string, because each substring to be matched is a single word, you can use [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fdb5cf0d5138938096f2b13729658c9c5df9149))

```
$str = ' red,     green,     blue ,orange ';
var_export(str_word_count($str,1));  // 1 means return all words in an indexed array
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'red',
  1 => 'green',
  2 => 'blue',
  3 => 'orange',
)
```

This can also be adapted for substrings beyond letters (and some hyphens and apostrophes -- if you read the fine print) by adding the necessary characters to the character mask / 3rd parameter.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5c29bbd0124ceaec0452b0f62cc02839f402ddb))

```
$str = " , Number1 ,     234,     0 ,4heaven's-sake  ,  ";
var_export(str_word_count($str,1,'0..9'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Number1',
  1 => '234',
  2 => '0',
  3 => '4heaven\'s-sake',
)
```

---

Again, I am treating this question very narrowly because of the sample string, but this will provide the same desired output:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c687f8a9b32aee202799b79ab1e58280b23460de))

```
$str = ' red,     green,     blue ,orange ';
var_export(preg_match_all('/[^, ]+/',$str,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

---

Finally, if you want to split on commas with optional leading or trailing spaces, here is the call: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9ePPV))

```
var_export(
    preg_split ('/ *,+ */', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for that.

```
$bar = preg_split ('/[,\s]+/', $str);
print_r ($bar);

/* Result:
  Array
  (
      [0] => red
      [1] => green
      [2] => blue
      [3] => orange
  )
 */
```

Comment: That will split on spaces in your elements

Comment: Move the comma to left of square braces to make the comma required.

Comment: Moving the comma to the left won't solve that.  Please check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/38300330/5079380

Answer (score -5):

```
$str = str_replace(" ","", $str);
```

Comment: Trim does more than this... It trims `\t\n\r\0\x0B` also

Comment: Not only that, but this will screw up elements with space.

Answer (score -12):

> trim and explode

$str = 'red,     green,     blue ,orange';

$str = trim($str);

$strArray = explode(',',$str);

print_r($strArray);

Comment: This only strips whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, not between each colour.