# Regular expression for some match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've a following regular expression

```
[^|]+(|[^|]+){15}
```

for the following line

```
|     1 |  2567 | Алма-атинська(І) вул.                     | 2     | 2      |5678     |Типовий лічил-|Санвузол          | 15.12.2016 | 10.11.2016 | 10.11.2020 | 23.10.2017 |            |    43.00 |bot       |
```

Its work fine, and I got all text between '|', but how can I pass any strings for these matches? For example, trim all backspaces, or delete some subsring.

Comment: so you want to remove extra spaces in between the whole string?

Comment: Please provide an output you would like to see

Comment: Your regex is equal to `[^|]+` and the question is unclear.

Comment: @pr1nc3, trim backspaces, and format like this: $m[0] = 1; $m[1] = 2567; $m[2] = Алма-атинська; - get text before '('. etc.

Comment: "how can I pass any regulars for this matches". What do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: Also, see [**How can I explode and trim whitespace?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347005/how-can-i-explode-and-trim-whitespace)

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I saw, thanks, it's really help me understood preg_match_all work.

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode()`, followed by `trim()` to remove additional spaces, etc. And finally use `array_filter` to remove blank values from the array:

```
$str = '|     1 |  2567 | Алма-атинська(І) вул.                     | 2     | 2      |5678     |Типовий лічил-|Санвузол          | 15.12.2016 | 10.11.2016 | 10.11.2020 | 23.10.2017 |            |    43.00 |bot       |';
$arr = array_filter(array_map(function($value){return trim($value);},explode('|', $str)));
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2567 [3] => Алма-атинська(І) вул. [4] => 2 [5] => 2 [6] => 5678 [7] => Типовий лічил- [8] => Санвузол [9] => 15.12.2016 [10] => 10.11.2016 [11] => 10.11.2020 [12] => 23.10.2017 [14] => 43.00 [15] => bot )
```

Comment: But if string not contains this pattern, how can I escape it? For example this line: `$str = "+-------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+-------+--------+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+";
`

Comment: the question you asked talks about spaces. this is a completely different string, having no spaces at all, and infact have + and - signs.