# Explode String by Comma and again with space

Tags: php, arrays, trim, explode

I have a string of numbers, like so:

```
$numbers = "one, two, three four, five";
```

I first explode it by comma:

```
$numbers_array = explode(",", $numbers);
```

My result is:

```
array(4) {
  [0] => string(3)  "one"
  [1] => string(4)  " two"
  [2] => string(11) " three four"
  [3] => string(5)  " five"
}
```

My question is, how can I achieve this?

```
array(5) { 
  [0] => string(3) "one" 
  [1] => string(4) "two" 
  [2] => string(6) "three" 
  [3] => string(5) "four" 
  [4] => string(5) "five"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I explode and trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347005/how-can-i-explode-and-trim-whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

This should split your code on spaces and commas:

```
$numbers = "one, two, three four, five";

$numbers_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $numbers);
```

You can then remove empty items by doing:

```
$filtered_numbers_array = array_filter($numbers_array);
```

Comment: that works! do you have any idea, if i have also an empty value that I want to keep? e.x: one, two, three, , four five, six?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: your last comment worked! you get it right (but not removing space) :/

Comment: You can use the flag PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY.
If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by preg_split().

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = "one, two, three four, five,";
$numbers_array = explode(",", $numbers);
$result = [];

foreach($numbers_array as $num){
  $result[] = trim($num);
}
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three four',
  3 => 'five'
)
```

And this way you can keep your empty item too.